# Proof of direct product using kernel and bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> **Prop.** Let $G = \{ x \in\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\mid x^{p-1} = 1 \}$, and let $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\to\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ be the group homomorphism induced by the map $\mathbb{Z}_p\to \mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{F}_p$. Then the composition $G\to\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\to\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is a bijection, and $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is the direct product of $G$ and $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The proof of this proposition says that since the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\to\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$, it suffices to show that the composition map $G\to \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is a bijection.

I don't understand how the kernel and bijection can deduce that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is the direct product of $G$ and $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$. If we use the First Isomorphism Theorem and the bijection $G\cong \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, we will have $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}/(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}\cong G$, but this seems not enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is the direct product of $G$ and $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: You have a group homomorphism of $G \times (1 + p \mathbb Z_p)$ to $\mathbb Z^*_p$ (given by inclusion on each of the factors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the bijection property $\Bbb F_p^\times$ is isomorphic to a (manifestly normal) subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ hence there is an ses:

> $$1\to \Bbb F_p^\times\to\Bbb Z_p^\times \to 1+p\Bbb Z_p\to 1$$

There is clearly a section $1+\Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z_p^\times$, hence this is a semi-direct product. Since the only map from $(1+\Bbb Z_p,\cdot)\cong(\Bbb Z_p, +)\to \text{Aut}(\Bbb F_p^\times)\cong C_{\phi(p-1)}$, the cyclic group of order $\phi(p-1)<p$ is trivial since the smallest index of any non-trivial subgroup of the DVR $\Bbb Z_p$ is $p$, in particular we would need an element of order divisible by $p$ in $C_{\phi(p-1)}$ which does not exist as $p$ is prime.

Honestly this is a much less satisfying way to go about the whole thing though, I recommend the much easier task of just using the section to show there is a unique way to write all elements of $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ as $gz$ for $g\in G$ and $z\in 1+p\Bbb Z_p$.